# When change dropdown value in parallel user input text field value should auto change

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want cascading dropdown when i click on dropdown its also change another user input text value. i want to show another value in user input text field. 
my table is like that

my table name is exercise_parent_type

```
id | perant_type_name | base_value
1      type1             10
2      type2             20
3      type3             30
4      type4             40
5      type5             50
```

i want to see base_value in user input text field
and in dropdown i want to see also Please select parent type name value

```
public function get_exercise_type_base_value(){
        $this->db->select('exercise_parent_type.base_value,exercise_parent_type.id');
        $this->db->from('exercise_parent_type');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $subcats[$row['id']][] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['base_value']);
            }

        return $subcats;
      //  return $query->result_array();       
    }
     public function get_exercise_type(){
        $this->db->select('exercise_parent_type.*');
        $this->db->from('exercise_parent_type');
        $query = $this->db->get();
         $query->result_array();

         foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $categories[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['perant_type_name']);
  }
  return $categories;
    }

<?php
  $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','godspeed');//set your database handler
  $query = "SELECT perant_type_name,id FROM dev_exercise_parent_type";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $categories[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['perant_type_name']);
  }

  $query = "SELECT id, base_value FROM dev_exercise_parent_type";
  $result = $db->query($query);

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $subcats[$row['id']][] = array("id" => $row['id'], "val" => $row['base_value']);
      }

  $jsonCats = json_encode($categories);
  $jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);
?>
<!docytpe html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      <?php
        echo "var categories = $jsonCats; \n";
        echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
      ?>
      function loadCategories(){
        var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
        select.onchange = updateSubCats;
        for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].id);          
        }
      }
      function updateSubCats(){
        var catSelect = this;
        var catid = this.value;
        var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
        subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
        for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
          subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload='loadCategories()'>
    <select id='categoriesSelect'>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="categoriesSelect" name="base_value" /> <!-- i want to see base_value in user input text field -->
    <!--select id='subcatsSelect'>
    </select-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question better. I want to suggest to follow this link where you will get a minimum idea. This is about the select tag of HTML and next drop-down is changed according to the first dropdown. This includes child-parent relationship.
[dependable dropdown](https://github.com/arif98741/dependable_dropdown_menu)

Comment: sir, here second number is dropdown using in on second number dropdown i want a user input text  in which show only one value